# Error "Couldn't reach API" when I try to log in

Tags: php, api, directus, headless-cms

I install Directus CMS via git clone successful. In the database 15 tables were created. In /config folder my projectkey.php file were created too. 
After installation I want to login with my credentials and get the error "Couldn't reach API".

```
In PHP Error log -> no entry
In Directus log -> no entry
```

REST calls:

```
authenticate/ -> Code 200; Response: data/user
projectkey/ -> Code 200; Response: data/api
ping/ -> Code 200; Response: Pong
```

In a working instance I have seen that in API Call `projectkey/` are more properties. For example `data/server` is missing in my instance.

Does anyone have any idea what this could be?

Answer (score 0):

Version 8.5.X solved my problem

Comment: I just installed ver. 8.7.2 and have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and found the solution in the project's [corresponding issue](https://github.com/directus/directus/issues/2510#issuecomment-636333239):

> Check that you're using HTTPS on webservers and local... that is a new requirement added in 8.7.2 due to a cookie policy change by Chrome et al. If it STILL is an issue, please open a new ticket with exact/specific information. Thanks!
>
> Also, just as a reminder, this is a VERY generic error and could shown for several different root causes. More specific error handling/codes is something we're adding in v9.

Enabling SSL fixed it for me.